# How to find out which Features of SQL Server installed on my machine

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2017

I know it has installed SQL Server 2017 Developer edition, but I need to find if I have all needed features for SSAS installed.

Basically I need to have this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 options you are looking for are not anymore in the sql server installer. 
These are optional packages you have to download. This mainly done because management studio and sql data tools have a seperate release schedule then SQL server.

[data tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt)

[SQl server Management studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

Comment: but  i thought  its right  now part of MSSQL 2017 developer edition ?

Comment: You don't need a license for using the tools. It's just not included in the install media of sql. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3428/sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-is-missing-after-installing-sql-server-2014/

Answer (score 1):

Open "SQL Server Installation Center" from the Windows Start menu. Click on "Tools" and then on "Installed SQL Server features discovery report"
[image]

Comment: Thanx but its 4 years old question :)

Comment: I know, I was looking for the answer to this question, so I thought to add it here just in case someone needs it.